# external dependencies need an extension?

Tags: quarkus

It's not clear for me if I'd like to add some jars to my projects should I make an extension for each one ?
Just read https://itnext.io/should-you-switch-to-quarkus-4b89eedfe5fe and it says gson is slower cause there's no extension and I guess maybe it was not compiled to native as it uses reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any dependencies inside your application as with other frameworks, an extension allow a technology to be integrated into Quarkus (injection via CDI bean, configuration via application.properties, native image support, ...) but it's not mandatory.

Or course, if you use a dependency not integrated as an extension, you cannot be sure that it will works in native, so be careful if you deploy your application as a native image some steps would need to be done.

In the article you cited, the issue is on native executables, and it shows that JSON-B outperforme GSON in this situation on this particular test, not that it uses a custom serialization (not the serialization provided by Quarkus via its extensions).
You can also note that the exemple didn't reuse the Gson object so it may be the cause of the slowness, by creating a Gson object on each request it will allocate a lot and the GC included inside SubstraatVM is not the same as the one in JVM mode (as with other optimizaton).

My point of view is that an extension will not impact the runtime performance of a dependency.

Comment: Thanks. Just yet a question
1. is there a way like maven goal to find a potential problematic jar ? I mean i.e. a reflection is used or just the native build crash then I would know   
2. currenty want to use json path lib and it crashed on native build with Unsupported method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1. Can do sth about it or it's graalvm issue?

Comment: 1. No, there is no way prior to using a JAR to know if it'll be compatible with GraalVM.
2. It's not GraalVM issue but native image limitation as it didn't support dynamic class definition (ClassLoader.defineClass1). You should discuss this with the json path library support/community/...